# Bash prompt is different when I am doing ssh using python pexpect library

Tags: python, ssh, spawn, pexpect

When I am connecting to Linux using ssh the bash prompt is `centos-1:~#`.

But when I am connecting to Linux using pexpect spawn the bash prompt is `\x1b]0;root@centos-1:~\x07centos-1:~# \r\n`.
What is causing this change and how do I get rid of this issue?

Please find the differences below.

```
>>> import pexpect
>>> child = pexpect.spawn("/bin/ssh",["root@172.23.63.10"]);
>>> child.readline();
'#############################################################\r\n'
>>> child.readline();
'#                                                           #\r\n'
>>> child.readline();
'#  This system is restricted to authorized users only.      #\r\n'
>>> child.readline();
'#  Unauthorized access or access attempts to this system    #\r\n'
>>> child.readline();
'#  or services are prohibited. All user activity is logged. #\r\n'
>>> child.readline();
'#  Evidence of unauthorized use collected during monitoring #\r\n'
>>> child.readline();
'#  may be provided to appropriate personnel for             #\r\n'
>>> child.readline();
'#  administrative, criminal or other adverse action.        #\r\n'
>>> child.readline();
'#                                                           #\r\n'
>>> child.readline();
'#############################################################\r\n'
>>> child.readline();
'X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0\r\n'
>>> child.readline();
'Last login: Wed Jan 30 08:48:32 2019 from 10.70.52.187\r\r\n'
>>> child.readline();
'#############################################################\r\n'
>>> child.sendline("");
1
>>> child.readline();
'\x1b]0;root@centos-1:~\x07\x1b[?1034hcentos-1:~# \r\n'
>>> child.sendline("");
1
>>> child.readline();
'\x1b]0;root@centos-1:~\x07centos-1:~# \r\n'
>>> child.sendline("");
1
>>> child.readline();
'\x1b]0;root@centos-1:~\x07centos-1:~# \r\n'

[greddy] # ssh root@172.23.63.10
#############################################################
#                                                           #
#  This system is restricted to authorized users only.      #
#  Unauthorized access or access attempts to this system    #
#  or services are prohibited. All user activity is logged. #
#  Evidence of unauthorized use collected during monitoring #
#  may be provided to appropriate personnel for             #
#  administrative, criminal or other adverse action.        #
#                                                           #
#############################################################
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
Last login: Wed Jan 30 08:51:17 2019 from 10.70.52.187
#############################################################
centos-1:~#
centos-1:~#
```

Comment: Your "normal" prompt is probably colored or bold, right? Should probably stop and think why and how that works :) (Both outputs are identical, one just happens to parse those magical bytes into something representable).

Comment: @Torxed.

print("\x1b[?1034hmsx121:/root # \r\n");
msx121:/root #

I can also see that, but when I connect to some other linux system using pexpect spawn i am not getting these characters, what wrong i might have done with this linux system? and the prompts for both the systems is same.